# htaccess problem with Chrome, but not Safari?

Tags: .htaccess, google-chrome

I have a very simple .htaccess file set up to redirect a 404 to a php script:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

This works as expected in Safari, but does not work in Google Chrome (on a Mac or a PC).

I have also put a 404.htm file to see if the php script was the problem, but had the same results.

Why would Chrome have a different experience over Safari for this?  I expected the .htaccess file to be a server-side redirect, so there shouldn't be any browser issues.

(All cache was cleared on all browsers before testing as well)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome displays specific error messages for 404 an such, you'll have to disable it manually in its options:

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95671

Comment: Thank you so much -- yes, that did it.  Unfortunately, I can't expect users to do that...so back to the drawing board.  :-)